# Dialog is not continuing from where it waited for user input

Tags: c#, .net, dialog, botframework, state

This code is using botframework 4

I have rootdialog which is calling an another dialog called choicedialog .From the choicedialog  i am returning the DialogturnResult(waiting) from BeginDialogAsync method.After that the bot wait for the input from the user.
when the user enter something it should call the ContinueAsync Method in the ChoiceDialog.But the bot is calling the Rootdailog  ContinueAsync .
what is the reason for this ?How can i solve this?

in the Controller onTurnAync Method

```
async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (turnContext.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {

                var dc = await Dialogs.CreateContextAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
                var dialogResult = await dc.ContinueDialogAsync();

                if (!dc.Context.Responded)
                {
                    // examine results from active dialog
                    switch (dialogResult.Status)
                    {
                        case DialogTurnStatus.Empty:
                            await dc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(RootDialog));
                            break;

                        case DialogTurnStatus.Waiting:
                            // The active dialog is waiting for a response from the user, so do nothing.
                            break;

                        case DialogTurnStatus.Complete:
                            await dc.EndDialogAsync();
                            break;

                        default:
                            await dc.CancelAllDialogsAsync();
                            break;
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

rootDialog

```
public override async Task<DialogTurnResult> BeginDialogAsync(DialogContext context, object options = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var activity = context.Context.Activity;
        context.SendTyping(activity);
            var response = DataFromService();
            if (response == null || response.StatusCode != 1)
            {
                await context.PostAsync(Messages.StandardErrorMessage);

            }

            if (response.Data != null)
            {

                return await dialog.BeginDialogAsync(context);

            }
            else
            {
                return new DialogTurnResult(DialogTurnStatus.Waiting);
            }

    }
```

ChoiceDialog

```
public override async Task<DialogTurnResult> BeginDialogAsync(DialogContext context, object options = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        choiceStep.SaveEntityDataInContext(context: context);

        IList<IMessageActivity> messages = GenerateMessageActivity(context);

        if (messages.IsCollectionValid())
        {
            foreach (var message in messages)
            {
                await context.PostActivityToUser(message);
            }
        }
        var dialogResult = new DialogTurnResult(DialogTurnStatus.Waiting);
        return dialogResult;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you saving the changes to `DialogState` anywhere. Usually this is done at the end of `OnTurnAsync`. You could possibly be using `AutoSaveStateMiddleware`, but you didn't mention that (and, frankly, I wouldn't recommend it).

Specifically you need to call `SaveChangesAsync` on the `BotState` instance  that you called `CreateProperty<DialogState>`. Usually this is `ConversationState`.

If you don't do this, every turn will start with an empty dialog stack, thus the behavior you're describing where the root dialog is always being run.

Comment: Thanks @DrewMarsh for your reply .I was using **AutoSaveStateMiddleware**. as per your suggestion i  am saving the state in **OnTurnAsync** after that also it is not helping me to achieve it.

Comment: Can you show the code for creating your DialogSet and your ConversationState setup?

Comment: HI @Drew The problem was with dailogSet. I haven't added the child dialogs in the DialogSet.So i added all the dialogs under the DilaogSet in the controller.Then it is working as expected .